# Is there any third party tool for exporting silverlight to powerpoint

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Is any third party tool to export silverlight controls to PPT slides.

Comment: check out this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/222172/Create-Powerpoint-slides-from-Silverlight-by-takin

Comment: I just need tools(for eg aspose for sildes) and i have checked this eg previous and applied but i'm not getting the sildes correctly(like i have grid of columns of 10 then one silde contains 8 columns and rest in another silde like that).